# How to display a SUM Value in a textbox from the another dataset, not from the tablix dataset name

Tags: reporting-services

I have two datasets to display in a table. Dataset1 which I named in a tablix is working well but when I get a value from dataset2, it does not display in the textbox.

This is what I've typed as expression:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!Type.Value, "Dataset2") = "pc", Sum(Fields!Hours.Value, "Dataset2"), 0)
```

I am expecting a sum of hours worked by pc but it displays 0 in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess your first `Type` value in the `Dataset2` does not have the value `pc`, thus it will display zero.

If you just want to display the sum of `Dataset2` use the following expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!Hours.Value, "Dataset2")
```